# How to get the class attribute value on click of a plus icon

Tags: jquery

I have got many div classes of  TreeMenu_Content  as it being a dynmic screen .

When clicked on the plus icon .

My question is , is it possible to get the lastItm_Wrap id value ?

I tried with

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function(event) {

    var idval = $(this).closest('div').find('.lastItm_Wrap').attr('id');

    alert(idval);
});
```

Is it possible to get the  **lastItm_Wrap attribute id** without using **TreeMenu_Content**

please let me know how to bring this value .

http://jsfiddle.net/bxbnkq64/

Comment: Please add the HTML to your question so we understand the relationship between the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function(event) {
    var idval = $(this).parents('.lastItm_Wrap').first().attr('id');
    alert(idval);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxbnkq64/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function(event) {

    var idval = $('.lastItm_Wrap').attr('id');

    alert(idval);
});
```

Try to access directly using that class if there is only one class

http://jsfiddle.net/bxbnkq64/2/